# How to get Pipe an email to a PHP Script and also save the file attached to the mail

Tags: php, email, pipe

I am using this email The code library here https://github.com/MonstaApps/PHP-IMAP-Fetcher/ to receive piped email and save it to the database.. I setup everything correctly but one issue is that attached file were not save to the specified directory.. I am getting Permission denied error back to my email
This is the error
mkdir(): Permission denied in /home/mybidrec/public_html/email-pipe/application.php on line 14

text

text

multipartPHP Warning:  file_put_contents(PayPal.PNG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/mybidrec/public_html/email-pipe/class.php on line 132

Please how can i go about it?

Comment: uh sorry not sure i understand what you're trying to do but uh if its a permission denied have checked line 14? where you're trying to create a directory? and/or if you have write access to that location?

Comment: @Fuseteam. Thank You... I am trying to fetch an email sent to the Script and then save the content of the Email to the database.. If the Email has an attachment it should be save to the server..  My Problem is that the script was not able to create directory and save the attached  file to the server.. It says Permission denied..

Comment: it sounds like the you don't have the write permission at location your script is trying to create a directory

Comment: @Fuseteam If i run the code from Browser, it create the directory and run successfully without an error.. But when i forward a mail to the script, that is when it return the error.. I wonder why it does this.. Is this a server issue or my code?

Comment: the question is where the script is creating the directory,
if we assume it's creating the directory on the server, then is it creating it in the www directory or outside of it, if outside of it, it will indeed return permission denied

Comment: @Fuseteam I think with what was written on the script, it suppose to create the directory on the same directory where the file is located.. is it possible that he do otherwise ?

Comment: @Fuseteam The script was to create the directory on the same location where the script was located.. That is what i write on the script file.. is it possible that it does otherwise ?

Comment: is the script on the server? if so then does have write permission, it all boils down to write permission i think
If it doesn't have write permission you will get "permission denied" when creating the directory
if it does have write permission and you get permission, i'm stumped myself or we're overlooking something

Comment: Thank You @Fuseteam I have find out that the heading i used for the script is coursing the issue.. as this has to do with piping email to the script in which the script should save any attachment coming with the email to the server.. i got rid of the error by (1) Changing this line "#!/usr/local/bin/php -q" at the beginning of my code to this "#!/usr/bin/php -q" (2) Setting permission for the folder in which the files were to save to 777.. After i did this, i see the script run successfully without returning error..

Comment: there we go then i guess we should summarize the solution in an answer

Comment: Okay, You should go ahead as i don't know what to write as statement

Comment: just write what you did to resolve your problem, that should be enough i believe, if something's unclear people will just comment on it for you :3